# Gnome 3 crashes while creating new Password Keyring

Tags: gnome3, crash, sabayon

I'm using Sabayon 10 with Gnome 3. The problem is Gnome crashes and restarts when I try to create new Password Keyring.

Passwords and Keys > + > Password Keyring > 'typing name & passwords' > CRASH

I cannot create that so can't log on to online accounts. The OS is clean, installed yesterday, no more desktops on it, but Fluxbox.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

--- EDIT ---

Using MATE I see `Can't communicate with gnome-keyring-daemon`.

Comment: why don't you create a new keyring from terminal?? try using seahorse for this

Comment: I'm quite new in linuxes and don't know how to do that yet

Comment: try this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring#Use_Without_GNOME sorry for late reply

Answer (score 1):

It´s probably a bug in GNOME keyring. You should file a bug report in your distro bug tracker.

Comment: Even if he is doing something wrong, applications should not just crash. +1 to file a bug report. Details on providing a good bug report would improve the answer though.